# How to determine the best index on a table with 3 nullable columns?

Tags: mysql, index, innodb, mysql-5.6, index-tuning

I am examining a `users` table similar to this:

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `email` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `password` varchar(81) DEFAULT NULL,
  `mobile_phone_number` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

I am not sure if I need a big index comprising the 3 primary searched and identifiers : `username`,`email`,`mobile_phone_number` . 
I need all of these fields to be searched as quick as possible. 
Main queries contain `where` conditions on either `email` and `mobile_phone_number` or `username`. As well as each on their own.

How can I determine the best index over these ?

My fear of using a index over all 3 is that it would not be efficient in some of my main queries as they are all nullable columns. Is the column beeing nullable even relevant to the index use ?

Comment: Given the information at hand, I would just create a single non-clustered index on the username column.  Don't apply any other indexes until you see what the performance actually looks like.  You might consider a filtered index if the incidence of null values for email or mobile_phone_number is low enough.

Comment: For the record, username is defined as `NOT NULL`, so it is not nullable.

Comment: Since Mysql doesn't support Index Skip Scan execution plan,  composite index won't be very useful. I'd rather keep it simple and create 3 indexes, one on each column .

Comment: @RolandoMySQLDBA sorry for the confusion, username needs to be null by default

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Decebal, Please consider the following, as the current answer is incomplete, flawed and built on an assumption.

First I will attempt to explain my previous statement.

1.) Incomplete (cardinality, prefixing and data types): Composite indexes and indexes in general need to remain lean to fit in memory, actually benefit performance and not over complicate nor confuse things. Therefor the only complete answer would be to test cardinality on your table in order to utilize an efficient index prefix length. The next step of completeness is to slim down your data types. It matters for sorting and other explicit/implicit MEMORY engine usage.

2.) Flawed (null-able UNIQUE composite indexes): The `contact_info_ndx` UNIQUE composite index in Rolando's answer contains null-able fields. This will effectively enforce a partial UNIQUE constraint. Any composite containing a NULL in one of the three fields will allow for duplicates, a NULL effectively breaks the constraint. MySQL doesn't know what a NULL is and therefor cannot judge it.

3.) Assumption (Necessity of UNIQUE constraints): This is quite an impacting assumption as a UNIQUE constraint should be avoided unless absolutely necessary. It add's overhead, circumvents an important performance enhancing mechanism (i.e. change buffer) and increases the probability of dead-locks through gap locks on the UNIQUE key when inserting in batches.

With that said, here are the steps that I would advise:

**Step 1:** Data type(s). (Not sure if this step is necessary as you mentioned that the table in your question is "similar" to that of your actual User table.)

- ID. In the case that your IDs are not negative, consider making your ID field unsigned.

  ```
  ALTER TABLE users MODIFY `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
  ```
- Email. Varchar(255) seems like overkill for an email field. Find the current max character count and use that to slim down a bit. E.g.

  ```
  SELECT MAX(CHAR_LENGTH(email))*2 FROM users;

  ALTER TABLE users MODIFY `email` varchar(...) DEFAULT NULL;
  ```
- mobile_phone_number. Pretty safe to assume 30 characters will be sufficient.

  ```
  ALTER TABLE users MODIFY `mobile_phone_number` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL;
  ```

**Step 2:** Cardinality and left most prefix.

On each field you will be installing an index, I would advise you to test how much of that field needs to be in the index for it to be effective and slim at the same time. I wrote a small statement to do just that. Replace the `table_name` with your table name and the `field_name` with your field name. i.e. for the field `email` on the table `users`:

```
SELECT total,
   total_distinct,
   field_min_length,
   field_avg_length,
   field_max_length,
   one,
   Format((one/total_distinct)*100, 2) '%',
   two,
   format((two/total_distinct)*100, 2) '%',
   three,
   format((three/total_distinct)*100, 2) '%',
   four,
   format((four/total_distinct)*100, 2) '%',
   five,
   format((five/total_distinct)*100, 2) '%',
   six,
   format((six/total_distinct)*100, 2) '%',
   seven,
   format((seven/total_distinct)*100, 2) '%',
   eight,
   format((eight/total_distinct)*100, 2) '%',
   nine,
   format((nine/total_distinct)*100, 2) '%',
   ten,
   format((ten/total_distinct)*100, 2) '%',
   eleven,
   format((eleven/total_distinct)*100, 2) '%',
   twelve,
   format((twelve/total_distinct)*100, 2) '%',
   thirteen,
   format((thirteen/total_distinct)*100, 2) '%',
   fourteen,
   format((fourteen/total_distinct)*100, 2) '%',
   fifteen,
   format((fifteen/total_distinct)*100, 2) '%',
   sixteen,
   format((sixteen/total_distinct)*100, 2) '%',
   seventeen,
   format((seventeen/total_distinct)*100, 2) '%',
   eighteen,
   format((eighteen/total_distinct)*100, 2) '%',
   nineteen,
   format((nineteen/total_distinct)*100, 2) '%',
   twenty,
   format((twenty/total)*100, 2) '%'
FROM   (
          SELECT count(*)                              total,
                 count(DISTINCT email)            total_distinct,
                 format(min(length(email)), 0)   AS field_min_length,
                 format(avg(length(email)), 0)   AS field_avg_length,
                 format(max(length(email)), 0)   AS field_max_length,
                 count(DISTINCT(LEFT(email,1)))  AS one,
                 count(DISTINCT(LEFT(email,2)))  AS two,
                 count(DISTINCT(LEFT(email,3)))  AS three,
                 count(DISTINCT(LEFT(email,4)))  AS four,
                 count(DISTINCT(LEFT(email,5)))  AS five,
                 count(DISTINCT(LEFT(email,6)))  AS six,
                 count(DISTINCT(LEFT(email,7)))  AS seven,
                 count(DISTINCT(LEFT(email,8)))  AS eight,
                 count(DISTINCT(LEFT(email,9)))  AS nine,
                 count(DISTINCT(LEFT(email,10))) AS ten,
                 count(DISTINCT(LEFT(email,11))) AS eleven,
                 count(DISTINCT(LEFT(email,12))) AS twelve,
                 count(DISTINCT(LEFT(email,13))) AS thirteen,
                 count(DISTINCT(LEFT(email,14))) AS fourteen,
                 count(DISTINCT(LEFT(email,15))) AS fifteen,
                 count(DISTINCT(LEFT(email,16))) AS sixteen,
                 count(DISTINCT(LEFT(email,17))) AS seventeen,
                 count(DISTINCT(LEFT(email,18))) AS eighteen,
                 count(DISTINCT(LEFT(email,19))) AS nineteen,
                 count(DISTINCT(LEFT(email,20))) AS twenty
          FROM   users) t1\G
```

Choose the prefix length with at least 98%. I.e.

```
ALTER TABLE users ADD index usr_eml_pswd (username(6),email(7),password(6));
```

**Result:**  After these changes your table DDL should look like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `email` varchar(52) DEFAULT NULL,
  `password` varchar(81) DEFAULT NULL,
  `mobile_phone_number` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `email` (`email`(7)),
  KEY `mobile_phone_nr` (`mobile_phone_number`(8)),
  KEY `usr_eml_nr` (`username`(6),`email`(7),`mobile_phone_number`(8))
) ENGINE=InnoDB
```

Change summary:

```
ALTER TABLE users
  MODIFY `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  MODIFY `email` varchar(52) DEFAULT NULL,
  MODIFY `mobile_phone_number` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  ADD index email (email(7)),
  ADD index mobile_phone_nr (mobile_phone_number(8)),
  ADD index usr_eml_nr (username(6), email(7), mobile_phone_number(8));
```

Depending on your queries, you might even be able to do with one or two of the above indexes or two composite instead of two single and one composite. It's poking around in the dark for me.

Comment: I agree this is a better answer, I have made the changes suggest at 1), I haven't used UNIQUE indexes as suggested by Rolando as I saw the assumption and did not help my cause. I am not sure about the cardinality point though, as to me, it appears that your answer assumes I am operating on a known dataset. I want to have users that have all those details, but I might have the majority of them using just the mobile phone in the future, whilst now the majority have only email address, username is something that all should have, what's your advice on that, now ?

Comment: My assumption about the data set (for the prefix length test) was based on your initial thread. You stated that you were examining an existing users table, not designing a new one. The cardinality test is only to determine the most efficient prefix length to your indexes. If the table is not filled yet, you can always run this test later when the table is filled and alter the index. The tip is also to be aware of the importance of lean indexes and the possibility to prefix. (1/2)

Comment: If you don't have enough data to determine the prefix length now, for certain fields, then skip this step for those fields until you do and use the full field length in the mean time. A database has an organic life cycle. The right approach would be to maintain a lean and efficient indexing scheme. However this is applied, is up to you and governed by the data. (2/2)

Comment: thanks @nashcoff, you are right I stated that I am examining an existing users table, but the main thing is that the users table is one of the most dynamic components and I am not sure if I should impose any constraints based on that cardinality, but I dropped the index on username as per your suggestion and test.

Comment: Using "prefix" indexes is a disaster.  Don't do it.

Comment: @RickJames, great explanation Rick.

Answer (score 3):

When looking up contact info, an index with `username, email, mobile_phone_number` would be great except for three small problems

1. uniqueness of username
2. uniqueness of email
3. uniqueness of mobile_phone_number

If `username` is supposed to be unique, then `username, email, mobile_phone_number` would just be overkill with index bloating.

Since `email` and `mobile_phone_number` are nullable, they need unique indexes as well.

If you create a unique index on `username`, `email` or `mobile_phone_number`, MySQL will disallow the insert for you on any individual uniqueness.

You could still create an index `username, email, mobile_phone_number` as a good covering index to retrieve all three columns when looking up by username with

```
SELECT username, email, mobile_phone_number
FROM users WHERE username = '...';
```

## SUGGESTION

Create the indexes to have the following

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `password` varchar(81) DEFAULT NULL,
  `mobile_phone_number` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `username` (`username`),
  UNIQUE KEY `email` (`email`),
  UNIQUE KEY `mobile_phone_number` (`mobile_phone_number`),
  UNIQUE KEY `contact_info_ndx` (`username`,`email`,`mobile_phone_number`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

by running

```
ALTER TABLE users
   ADD UNIQUE KEY (`username`),
   ADD UNIQUE KEY `email` (`email`),
   ADD UNIQUE KEY `mobile_phone_number` (`mobile_phone_number`),
   ADD UNIQUE KEY `contact_info_ndx` (`username`,`email`,`mobile_phone_number`)
;
```

Comment: `UNIQUE(email)` allows multiple records with email `NULL` in mysql. As far as I know only SQLServer treats null the same as other values when it comes to `unique`

Comment: @a1ex07 Ugh, you are right. I just tried on my laptop.

Comment: @a1ex07 I changed my answer in light of your observation. Thank you.

Comment: @ RolandoMySQLDBA: np, but why the last(composite) index ?  I guess it'll be used only when it's covered ...  Never mind, I found explanation in your answer. :)

Comment: @a1ex07 That's right. I added the SELECT just above the SUGGESTION header that would harness the Covering index .

Comment: thanks @RolandoMySQLDBA, can't use the `unique` approach tough as I am working on old data that still has some problems, do you think it would be a big difference in performance if I use just the normal index ?

Comment: If you do not use unique indexes, you will have to enforce uniqueness from the application layer. Sounds a little yucky to me.

Comment: There is no need for `UNIQUE` on that composite index; it is composed of 3 already-unique columns.